# Do the gods incarnate as mythical creatures in other lokas?

Tags: puranas, avatars, lokas

Gods are often born on Earth (Bhulok). As you know these incarnations are known as *avatars*. A popularly known avatars is Shree Krishna. However as per my knowledge, avatars are born as humans (Manava) on Bhulok. Are there any avatars who are not Manavas, e.g. Apsaras, Nagas in other lokas? If not, why don't the gods incarnate as mythical creatures in other lokas?

Comment: Mohini avatar is kind of apsara and what about Narasimha avatar?

Comment: When I said avatars,I meant that the gods are born from their mothers and grow from a child into an adult like Rama and Krishna

Comment: Avatara is just a descent of God from his abode (Vaikuntha in Vishnu's case) to the other realms. So it can be in any form. As you will know, he has taken avataras as a fish (Matsya), a tortoise (Kurma), Swan (Hamsa), boar (Varaha) etc. You can call Vamana avatara as an incarnation of Vishnu as a **deva**, since he was born to Aditi and Kashyapa.

Comment: @Surya Why don't the gods take virth as other species in other lokas as frequently as they take birth on Warth on Manavas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would seem that the Avatars of the Lord are more numerous on Earth. But that is only **because the scriptures that we have talk in more detail about our own Loka or the ones that are relevant to us** rather than the others with whom we have no connection.

[Shrimad Bhagavatam Canto 8. Chapter 14](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OveYh2v-1roC&pg=PT382&lpg=PT382&dq=manvantara%20purana&source=bl&ots=xDp33CXT_j&sig=nR2AT_g6NF5xpJUcjtmfn69kj2k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP_oW0kLjVAhVHSiYKHZQ_AH4Q6AEIUTAH#v=onepage&q=manvantara%20purana&f=false) clearly mentions that the Avatars in different Manvantars are for the guidance of Manu, the sons of Manu, the rishis and other beings. Even if we just see the list of Manvantars, we can still find some Avatars who were neither born on Earth nor lived here:

1. The **VARAH** incarnation definitely did not happen on Earth but outside it only then the Divine Boar could have lifted the planet Earth on his tusks.

[image]

2. The **FOUR KUMARS** again were not born on Earth rather they emerged from Brahma's min in his own Loka. They frequently travel through different worlds as mentioned in many stories from the Bhagvatam.

[image]
[image]

3. The horse-headed **HAYAGRIVA AVATAR** didn't happen on our Loka as its purpose was to return the Vedas that had escaped from Brahma's mouth back to him.
4. The **YAJNA AVATAR** of Lord Vishnu again was not on our Loka rather he was the king of Swarga and became Indra:

[image]

5. **VAMAN AVATAR** also did not concern itself with our Loka rather he measured all the existing Lokas in his three steps:

[image]

6. Lord took the **MOHINI** and **KURMA** forms at the shore of Ksheer Sagar where the **Samudra Mantha** was taking place.

[image]

We can see from these examples that the Lord is definitely born in different forms all over his creation wherever he is required & there may be more that are not recorded in our scriptures.

Comment: By different species, I mean the ones which already are created like Nagas and Gandharvas. Thus, only your answers of the Sanat Kumaras, Yajna and Vamana

Comment: For the record, Vamana and Yagna were both born on earth.  Vamana was born in the Siddhashrama in the Himalayas, and Yagna was a human being who became the king of the gods when they had no king.